# unclear pandas SettingWithCopyWarning while adding a boolean column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a bunch of columns and I want to add a column that contains the answer to a boolean operation performed on a couple of other columns:

```py
df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)
```

So basically I want to record each time we hit a minimum number of "items" after filtering out some items that weren't suitable for display. Pretty simple logic, I reckon.

While it works and produces the expected outcome, the code above gives me a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I don't understand why. I've tried the following:

```py
df['hitMinValue'] = ((df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)).copy()
df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']).copy() & (df['filteredItems'] > 0).copy()
```

Neither of which worked: I still get the same warning. It seems there are lots of questions regarding the `SettingWithCopyWarning` on SO, but none seemed to cover such a simple example. I mean I don't even have a `for` loop in there.

Can anyone explain what's happening here and how I may get rid of the warning?

Comment: What is your complete code, before `df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)` ? Because in code before is necessary add `.copy`

Comment: wherever you define `df` before this code as `df = xyz`, use `df = xyz.copy()`

Comment: @jezrael your suggestion made me try to add `.copy()` throughout my code whenever I did `some_df = some_other_df.do_stuff(...)`. Eventually I stopped getting that warning when I added the copy to `df = another_df.dropna().copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

A few lines above the line

```py
df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)
```

I had a line the following line:

```py
df = another_df.dropna()
...
df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)
```

It seems that was the place I should have added the `.copy()`. I edited the line as follows:

```py
df = another_df.dropna().copy()
...
df['hitMinValue'] = (df['availableItems'] == df['minItemsRequired']) & (df['filteredItems'] > 0)
```

And that got rid of the warning. What confused me is that the warning originated from the second line.